# Using Main to execute classes

Tags: java

Newish to coding and very new to Java. I'm trying to make a text encryptor that accepts text and spits it back out in Hexadecimal. I have a textScanner.java which scans console inputs for text, and an ecryptor.java that converts the scanned text to hexadecimal. How do i get these two to work together in my Main.java?

Tried making constructors with no luck

```
/*Main.java*/
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
   /*what should i put in here*/
  }
}

/*encryptor.java*/
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class encryptor
{
  public static String toHexadecimal (String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
  {
    byte[]myBytes = text.getBytes ("UTF-8");
    System.out.println(toHexadecimal (textScanner.scanner()));
    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary (myBytes);
  }
}

/*textScanner.java*/
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class textScanner
{
  public static String scanner () throws UnsupportedEncodingException
  {
     Scanner scanA = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println ("Please enter the text to be encrypted");
      String plainText = scanA.next ();
      scanA.close();
      return plainText;
  }
}
```

input : goodmorning stackoverflow

output : 20 67 6f 6f 64 6d 6f 72 6e 69 6e 67 20 73 74 61 63 6b 6f 76 65 72 66 6c 6f 77

Comment: I would suggest splitting the two classes apart into two separate files (within the same folder).

Comment: I think they already did that, hence the comments.

Comment: Your method `Encrytor#toHexadecimal` already invoke `TextScanner#scanner`, why not using `byte[] myBytes = textScanner().getBytes("UTF-8");` in this method and just put `System.out.println(encryptor.toHexadecimal());` in your `main` method? (and remove `System.out.println(toHexadecimal (textScanner.scanner()));` in `Ecnryptor#toHexadecimal`).

Comment: And I suggest to use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()` from [StandardCharsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8) instead of `"UTF-8"`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using static methods, you don't need to construct any objects.

```
public static void main (String[]args)
{
  String plainText = textScanner.scanner();
  encryptor.toHexadecimal(plainText);
}
```

Comment: It compiles, but on text entry it returns this

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)

 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)

 at textScanner.scanner(textScanner.java:11)

 at encryptor.toHexadecimal(encryptor.java:10)

 at Main.main(Main.java:10)

Comment: This is because you call `next()` before the user has pressed a key. You should probably wait and then check with `hasNext()` if the user has made an input. My suggestion however would be to use a BufferedInputReader or similar to read entire lines instead of single characters.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses constructors without static methods:
Also try to have the first letter of each class name capitalized

TextScanner

```
public class TextScanner
{
    public String scanner () throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        Scanner scanA = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Please enter the text to be encrypted");
        String plainText = scanA.next ();
        scanA.close();
        return plainText;
    }
}
```

Encryptor

```
public class Encryptor {
    public String toHexadecimal (String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        byte[]myBytes = text.getBytes ("UTF-8");
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary (myBytes);
    }
}
```

Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[]args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        TextScanner ts = new TextScanner();
        String input = ts.scanner();
        Encryptor encryptor = new Encryptor();
        String output = encryptor.toHexadecimal(input);
        System.out.println("Output: " + output);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter the text to be encrypted
goodmorning stackoverflow
Output: 676F6F646D6F726E696E67
```